# How interpret the dual lattice $\Gamma^*$?

Tags: graph-theory, riemannian-geometry, intuition, integer-lattices

In the book *Eigenvalues in Riemannian Geometry* of Isaac Chavel page $28$ - $29$, they talk about the *lattice* $\Gamma$  and it is defined as $$\Gamma = \left\{\sum_{j=1}^n \alpha^j v_j : \alpha^j \in \mathbb{Z}, j=1,\dots, n\right\}.$$ If I take the canonical basis (simplifying the problem) $v_1=(1,0)$, $v_2=(0,\sqrt{2})$, then I obtain $\Gamma=\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0  \\
  0 & \sqrt{2}  
 \end{pmatrix}\mathbb{Z}^2$. Now, it is possible to associate to the lattice $\Gamma,$ the *dual lattice*, $\Gamma^*$, given by $$\Gamma^*=\{y \in \mathbb{R}^n : \langle x,y\rangle \in \mathbb{Z} \text{ for all } x \in \Gamma\}.$$

**Questions :** Does it exist a way to interpret the dual lattice $\Gamma^*$ graphically, a sketch? How should we interpret this concept in the resolution of the spectrum on the torus?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The spectrum of the $n$ torus is obvious since it is the spectrum of a $n$ dimensional box (as in dimension $1$ : Fourier series in $\sin$).

Comment: «How should we interpret this concept in the resolution of the spectrum on the torus?» Does the book not tell you why it introduced the dual lattice?